# Azure PushAsync() error

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I encounter a wired error when use PushAsync() function to sync data from local database to Azure. f I take  InsertAsync(item) action only once, the sync works wells. But if I did more than two times, the PushAsync() will throw an exception that ask me to check pushasync result.

I followed this tutorial http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/

Comment: The PushAsync result should have a MobileServiceTableOperationError. Can you share the properties of that error?

Comment: I'm a beginner to azure service, how to see MobileServiceTableOperationError in visual studio?

Comment: I just added more info on another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28225969/3516125

Comment: It's said " Error: an error occurred while sending the request"

Comment: Does that error come from error.Result or error.RawResult? Have you made any changes to the tutorial?

Comment: Another thing you can do is add trace output to your requests to see exactly what is being sent: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/http-message-handlers-with-the-new-version-of-azure-mobile-services-client-for-windows-store-apps/. This will write out the HTTP requests to the Debug Output window. If you do that and can edit your oriignal question with the results, that may help.

Comment: after catch(MobileServicePushFailedException ex),  ex.PushResult.Errors= count 0;                                                    ex.PushResult ={Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServicePushCompletionResult}
    Errors: Count = 0
    Status: CancelledByNetworkError

Comment: Sure, I will look that website carefully

Comment: @ brettsam I read the website you mentioned, but to add a tracehandler(), vs says miss assembly reference. I thought only after I target the app to .Net framework that I will be able to add System.Web.Handlers

Comment: You should be able to add it in your .Shared project. Does that not work? Add it where the MobileServiceClient is created: public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
    "http://localhost:51281", "", new TraceHandler()
);